# Unable to add files to chrome developer tools sources workspace

Tags: javascript, debugging, filesystems, google-chrome-devtools

[image: drag and drop folders in the Sources panel]

The above notice asks us to drag and drop folders in the **Sources** panel. So, our debugging efforts can stay.

However, when I try to drag and drop folders to it, it doesn't allow me to do so. The cursor changes from normal to **blocked**.

Have anyone else also faced the same kind of issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When it says to Drag and Drop the folders into the Sources panel, it means from your desktop environment, not from within the panel itself. For example:

[image: Drag and Drop to Workspace]

You need to click Allow when you see the following message at the top of the window:
[image: Workspace Permission]

Comment: You might have to open a new tab, in case you cant see the DevTools notification.

Comment: clicking Allow sometime it works, sometime it doesnt:(